# Upload Image to Amazon S3 (How to get Signature and Policy Doc)

Tags: jquery, cordova, bucket

In my android cordova/phonegap v2.8 app am trying to upload an image to my amazon s3 bucket.
I already have the code that performs the upload.

```
 function upload_media(imgURI) {
  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.fileKey="file";
  var time = new Date().getTime();
  var fileName = time+".jpg";
  options.fileName = fileName;
  options.mimeType ="image/jpeg";
  options.chunkedMode = false;

  var uri = encodeURI("http://<your bucket name>.s3.amazonaws.com/");

  var policyDoc = '<Base 64 policy doc>';
  var signature = '<Generated Signature>';
  var params = {
  "key": "media/"+fileName,
  "AWSAccessKeyId": "<Your AWS Access Key>",
  "acl": "public-read",
  "policy": policyDoc,
  "signature": signature,
   "Content-Type": ""
  };
  options.params = params;

  var ft = new FileTransfer();
  ft.upload(imgURI, uri, function() {
  console.log("Success! :)");
  },
  function() {
  console.log("Failure! :(");
 }, options);
  }
```

But i don't know to get and include the signature and policy doc in the above script.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue a while ago while working with Cordova. This is a helpful link that helped me make my Python Script that generates a policy and signature. I hope it's helpful!

[Generating Amazon S3 CORS signature with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165921/generating-amazon-s3-cors-signature-with-python)

Comment: The referenced question doesn't have an accepted answer, could you be more specific about what Donnie should be looking for in this post, and how it applies to his question?